# MTLBuffer with MTLStorageModePrivate mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpu, metal, mtlbuffer

I'm relatively new to the Metal, and I have a pretty straight-forward question. I simply can not init `MTLBuffer` with `MTLStorageModePrivate` option:

```
id<MTLBuffer> privateBuff = [device newBufferWithLength:dataLength options:MTLStorageModePrivate];
```

Compiler gives me an assert with that text:

```
-[MTLDebugDevice validateResourceOptions:isTexture:isIOSurface:]:437: failed assertion `options 0x2 conveys invalid cpuCacheMode of 0x2'
```

And it doesn't make much sense. I'm creating a buffer which can be accessed only from GPU, so I need no cpu cache modes whatsoever for this particular entity. I suppose I need to turn off that cpu cache mode, but how?

I looked through `MTLCPUCacheMode`, but it has nothing regarding turning cpu cache mode completely off.

Interesting note: I absolutely can create `MTLHeap` with `MTLStorageModePrivate`, but not `MTLBuffer`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE:* I can create `MTLBuffer` with `MTLStorageModePrivate` by using `MTLHeap`. It looks something like this:

```
    MTLHeapDescriptor *heapDescriptor = [MTLHeapDescriptor new];
    heapDescriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
    heapDescriptor.size = 0;

    MTLSizeAndAlign sizeAndAlign = [device heapBufferSizeAndAlignWithLength:lutSharedBuffer.length options:MTLResourceStorageModePrivate];
    sizeAndAlign.size += (sizeAndAlign.size & (sizeAndAlign.align - 1)) + sizeAndAlign.align;
    heapDescriptor.size += sizeAndAlign.size;

    privateHeap = [device newHeapWithDescriptor:heapDescriptor];

    privateBuff = [privateHeap newBufferWithLength:lutSharedBuffer.length options:MTLResourceStorageModePrivate]; //now it works!
```

But it's still not possible to do without the heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you're using the incorrect enum to specify your resource options. In your first snippet, you use `MTLStorageModePrivate`, but you should be using `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate`, which contains a bit shift to place the storage mode in the correct bits.

```
MTLResourceStorageModePrivate = MTLStorageModePrivate << MTLResourceStorageModeShift
```

In Swift, this would have caused a compile-time error.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, sir! Big thanks for your help!